# List of expired purchases in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Is there any way to get a list of expired purchases in iOS app?
Actually, I need to figure out if user made purchase and this purchase now is expired. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you scan through the receipt file you can see all past purchases. You will find this code very helpful for parsing the file and getting a list of the purchases made: https://github.com/rmaddy/VerifyStoreReceiptiOS